# WinInet CFtpConnection::openfile multiple files

Tags: c++, ftp, connection, wininet

I'm trying to write an aplication, that works with files on ftp server. I need to open several files in one ftp connection. I do this

```
CInternetSession session(_T("Session1"));
CFtpConnection* pConnect = NULL;
CInternetFile* pFile1;
CInternetFile* pFile2;

pConnect = session.GetFtpConnection(_T("10.0.172.113"), _T("user11"), _T("12345")); 

pFile1 = pConnect->OpenFile(L"folder1\\1.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY);
pFile2 = pConnect->OpenFile(L"folder1\\2.txt",GENERIC_READ,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY);

pConnect->Close();
```

But opening 2.txt thrown exception.
Is there a way to open two files without creating a new ftp connection?

Answer (score 1):

No, no way http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/1st6z7sc.aspx:

> After calling OpenFile and until calling CInternetConnection::Close,
>   the application can only call CInternetFile::Read,
>   CInternetFile::Write, CInternetConnection::Close, or
>   CFtpFileFind::FindFile. **Calls to other FTP functions for the same FTP
>   session will fail and set the error code to FTP_ETRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS**.